# Error while trying to copy mysql table from one database to another

Tags: mysql

I want to copy mysql table from one database to another using mysql command line

I am trying to executing commmand

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `db1.tablename`; CREATE TABLE `db1.tablename` like `db2.tablename`;
```

but it is giving me error no database is selected.

but if I fire

```
use db2
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `db1.tablename`; CREATE TABLE `db1.tablename` like `db2.tablename`;
```

then it is create table db1.tablename inside db 2.

How to fix it ?

Comment: then error is db1.db1.tablename doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think your create statement should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `db1.tablename` SELECT * FROM `db2.tablename`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The table name in your query includes the database name without separation. It should be something like:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `db1`.`tablename`; 
CREATE TABLE `db1`.tablename` like `db2`.`tablename`;
```